# Numpy's mean and standard deviation with Numba on Python

Tags: python, numba, jit

I am trying to use Numpy's mean and standard deviation functions insinde a function and they don't seem to be compatible with Numba, although [Numba documentation states them as compatible](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html).

My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import numba


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# @numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def nmeanstd(a, n):
    b = []; c = []
    for i in range(n):
        b.append(np.mean(a))
        c.append(np.std(a))
    
    return b, c

mean, std = nmeanstd(a, 10)
```

The output when looking at `mean` and `std` is the expected:

```
mean
Out[31]: [3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5]

std
Out[32]: 
[1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933,
 1.707825127659933]
```

But I don't know why, when I uncomment the `@numba.jit` function the following message appears:

```
TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<function mean at 0x11a0e6e50>) found for signature:
 
mean(reflected list(int64)<iv=None>)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'mean': File: numba/core/typing/npydecl.py: Line 378.
        With argument(s): '(reflected list(int64)<iv=None>)':
       No match.

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function mean at 0x11a0e6e50>)
```

And the same for `std` if I comment the line in which I compute the mean. What is happening? I though they would be running with `numba` correctly. Do you know any way of computing the mean and the standard deviation using Numba?

Comment: You really should avoid using lists if you want an efficient code (unless you are working with a *unbounded* set of items, which is not the case here). Note that Numba does not supports well Python lists since they can contains items of different types. Numba has its own typed lists (but you need to convert them from/to python list which is slow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message shows that Numba does not know how to compute the `mean` of a `list`. Your code works fine (with `@jit`) if the input list is first converted to a numpy array:

```
mean, std = nmeanstd(np.array(a), 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows NumPy arrays work directly with Numba and are very efficient.

The code works if you convert `a` into a NumPy array.

```
mean, std = nmeanstd(np.array(a), 10)
```